# Let $f$ be an integrable function on a Jordan set $D$. Prove that $|f|$ is integrable on $D$

Tags: calculus

Assume that $f$ is an integrable function on a Jordan set $D$. In order to that $|f|$ is integrable on $D$, we need to show that $-f$ is integrable on $D$ as well.

Since $f$ is an integrable function on a Jordan set $D$, $ \alpha f$ is integrable on $D$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb R$, so $-f =(-1)f$ is integrable on $D$. Since both $f$ and $-f$ is integrable on $D$, $|f|$ is integrable on $D$.

This is how I understand the problem, but I don't think it's that easy. So I wonder if anyone could tell if I make any mistake?

Comment: Careful, $|f|=\max(f,0)-\min(f,0)$. You need to show that if $f$ is integrable, so are $\max(f,0)$ and $\min(f,0)$.

Comment: oh, I thought $|f|$ is the absolute value of the function, thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is! ${}{}$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff I deleted my comment I read wrongly sorry

Comment: What's your definition of *integrable*? Since you're talking about Jordan sets, I assume you mean *riemann*-integrable?

Comment: @fgp yes, it can be any type of integral, I can also use the Darboux sum , which implies Riemann integral. As long as it's in $\mathbb R^2$

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Can you tell me what is $(f,0)$? I've never seen anything like this.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif I think you need to start from a *specific* definition of *integral* and *integrable*. Basically, what you need to show is that the positive and negative parts cannot cancel each other in troublesome ways. Note that this *can* happen for improper riemann integrals, so whatever way you prove this, the prove must include a step that fails for improper riemann integrals..

Comment: @fgp ok, I  prefer to start with the Darboux integral, that says $f(x,y)$ is Darboux intrgrable on $D$, if there exists a partition $P$ such that $U(f,P)=L(f,P)$. Since $f$ is integrable, so I got this part covered. For the negative part, isn't that $U(f,P)=L(f',P)$? $f'$ is negative part of $f$.

I'm not sure I understand this part"you need to show is that the positive and negative parts cannot cancel each other in troublesome ways. "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to show $f^+$ and $f^-$ are both integrable, I will do $f^+$ the other case is similar. After showing that we get $f^++f^-$ integrable, i.e $|f|$ is integrable.Let $M_s,m_s$  denote the max and min over $S$. If $M_s(f)\ge0$ where $S$ is a rectangle in $D$ then $$M_s(f^+)-m_s(f^+) = M_s(f)-m_s(f^+) \le M_s(f)-m_s(f)$$

Now if $M_s(f)\le 0$ then $M_s(f^+)-m_s(f^+)=0 \le M_s(f)-m_s(f)$.

By integrability of $f$ given $\varepsilon >0$ there is a partition  $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P)\le \varepsilon$.
$$U(f^+,P)-L(f^+,P)=\sum_{S \in P}vol(S)(M_s(f^+)-m_s(f^+))\le \sum_{S \in P}vol(S)(M_s(f)-m_s(f))= U(f,P)-L(f,P)\le \varepsilon$$
Then $f^+$ is integrable.

$f^+=\max(f,0)$ and $f^-=\max(-f,0)$

Comment: may I have a question please? $f \leq f^+$ right, so how can you have $M_s(f^+)-m_s(f^+)=M_s(f)-m_s(f^+)$?

Comment: $f=f^+$ when $f\ge 0$ then the maximum of $f$ is that of $f^+$ only when the maximum of $f$ is positive. I took the two cases in the answer.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif Does that make it clearer?

Comment: ok, I need to think more to understand this. My professor didn't touch anything on 2 sections about integral over rectangle and Jordan set, so I kinda stumble on these materials,Thanks.

Comment: The point of integrating over a Jordan measurable set is so your integral is defined. If you have any more questions ask.

Comment: my next question is , when the maximum value of $f$ is non positive then the max = the min? I'm not sure I can see this.

Comment: @DianeVanderwaif  $M_s(f^+)=0$ when $M_s(f)<0$ and since $M_s(f^+)>m_s(f^+)$ they are both zero (since $m_s(f^+)\ge 0$)

Comment: I think I kinda understand it now, I'll try to work on $f^-$ case and see how much I understand it. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad I could help, if you find the case for $f^-$ annoying try using a different definition for it which is $\min(f,0)$(Its the same thing)